# Using ebay Feed API with R

Tags: r, rest, api, get, ebay-api

I am trying to call the ebay Feed API using R but don't understand the syntax to be used, seems like I am missing the headers in the call to the API:

```
> res <- GET(paste0("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216"))
> res
Response [https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216]
  Date: 2019-12-21 08:39
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 228 B
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorId" : 1002,
    "domain" : "OAuth",
    "category" : "REQUEST",
    "message" : "Missing access token",
    "longMessage" : "Access token is missing in the Authorization HTTP request header."
  }
```

Where should be the headers?
I have seen something like this, adding parameters, would that be going on the right path? `payload` being a list of different authentication elements:

```
res_bis <- GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216", authenticate() = payload, encode = "form", verbose())
```

Help much appreciated!

**EDIT1**:
I saw an information about HTTP headers:

> HTTP request headers:   Content-Type – Must be set
>   to:application/x-www-form-urlencoded   Authorization – The word "Basic
>   " followed by your Base64-encoded OAuth credentials(client_id:client_secret).

I then tried the following but still got same error:

```
 GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216", add_headers("Basic client_id:client_secret"))
```

**EDIT2**: Updating my code following Andrea's help:

```
> GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216", 
+     add_headers(client_id = paste0("Basic", " ",your_token)), content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  )

Response [https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216]
  Date: 2019-12-21 12:17
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 228 B
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorId" : 1002,
    "domain" : "OAuth",
    "category" : "REQUEST",
    "message" : "Missing access token",
    "longMessage" : "Access token is missing in the Authorization HTTP request header."
  } ]
>
```

**EDIT3**:
Thanks to Andrea I managed to get my `access token`:
[image]

But I still get the same error when I do:

```
your_token= "XXXXXXXXX"
GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216", add_headers(client_id = paste0("Basic", " ",your_token)), content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  )

Response [https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216]
  Date: 2019-12-22 17:56
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 228 B
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorId" : 1002,
    "domain" : "OAuth",
    "category" : "REQUEST",
    "message" : "Missing access token",
    "longMessage" : "Access token is missing in the Authorization HTTP request header."
  } ]
```

Comment: I would probably go for [`add_headers()`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/add_headers.html) and pass the token as arguments in that function.

Comment: Thx, you're right. Let me edit my post with more info.

Comment: Try with `add_headers(content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), client_id = paste0("Basic", " ",your_token)`

Comment: My bad, can't edit the comment anymore. The `content_type()` call should be placed in in the main `GET()` call.

Comment: Thx, I stil can't get the response, see my 2nd edit. Hope I wrote it correctly.

Comment: Looking at the api docs you should first obtain an [access token](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-authorization-code-grant.html) before calling the api for data. After that you'll have to pass your access token in the [`Authorization`](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html) header to authenticate your subsequent api calls.

Comment: Thx a lot Andrea, I got the access token but the way I insert it in the GET call seems not to be correct still. See Edit3

Comment: No worries, been there before. Try something like `GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216", add_headers(Authorization = paste0("Bearer", " ",your_token)))`. At [this](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html) this page you can find more info for the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Andrea, your last suggestion seems to be working! Well I did not get the data expected (got 403 status code error from Ebay and many empty fields from Ebay API) but after investigating, I think this is more related to my Ebay application not being authorized yet by Ebay. I hope I'm write on this, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our exchange above, the main issue was a lack of understanding of how ebay feed api [auth flows](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html).
First, it is necessary to acquire an Authorization token to authenthicate future api requests.

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonify)

api_token <- "your_token_string"

# Get authorization token
auth_token_res <- GET("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token",
                      add_headers(client_id = paste0("Basic", " ",api_token)),
                      content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) %>% 
  fromJSON()

access_token <- auth_token_res[["access_token"]]  # parse it from JSON resp
```

That token will be then passed in future calls with `add_headers()` just like before:

```r
# Make request
feed_res <- GET("https://api.ebay.com/buy/feed/v1_beta/item?feed_scope=ALL_ACTIVE&category_id=625&date=20191216",
                add_headers(Authorization = paste0("Bearer", " ",access_token)))

# ... parse fields as needed from JSON  response
```